# Problem launching application from menu in KDE Gentoo linux

Tags: linux, gentoo, kde5

I followed this [guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64) to install Gentoo +systemd+KDE.
After booting in gentoo I noticed an unusual behaviour.

- once booted I can launch applications, only if there are no WiFi  connection being used.
- once connected to any WiFi network KDE application refuse to launch.
- And now even when I disconnect WiFi connection I can't launch any applications from menu.

After clicking on any application from menu it momentarily appears with blue spinning circle and then disappears
[KDE 5 vlc loading](https://photos.app.goo.gl/8zKYwnYLg1i5V1UC6)

Another thing I noticed

- after connecting to WiFi, KDE gives broken login screen error which otherwise not occurs

How can I solve this problem? If any outputs required feel free to ask  !! and Thanks for help in advance !!

Comment: Try starting the program from the command line in a terminal window to see if some error message is printed.

Comment: Ran one program from terminal and it worked flawlessly ; ran another program directly and it ran flawlessly and now everything is running perfectly.Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Johan Myréen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/187960/johan-myr%c3%a9en)'s comment turned out to solve the problem:

Start the program from the command line in a terminal window.